# how come my gaming pc overheats when connected to my tv?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, cooling, gaming

As stated on the question, I have had some rather uncomfortable system failures due to overheating. When I was on my 23" Full HD (1920 x 1080) LED monitor the symptoms have not appeared, but when I connected my rig to my 49" 4K TV, using Full HD (1920 x 1080) resolution, the system overheated to the point I perceived the burnt-varnish scent characteristic of PSU burn-outs. Also, the system booted some times and the interior of the case was very hot.

Would the load on the graphics card for displaying the same resolution on a much bigger screen attone for the excess heat? If so, how to deal with it?

Comment: Tell us something about the hardware used.  Tell us actual temperatures being reported.

Comment: 650W PSU (some 4 or 5 years old), motherboard is an ASUS Z97M-PLUS/BR, CPU is an i5 4690K, 8GiB Corsair Vengeance RAM. No O/C. As for temperatures, I can only tell that on TV were significant higher than on the monitor, but unfortunately I don't have any reports on it - is there some piece of software that I could run on the background to monitor the temperature correctly? Also, OS is Windows 10 64-bit.

Comment: So you are using the iGPU to push 1080p to a 49" monitor?  Are we talking resolutions higher then 2K?  There are lots of programs to report the temperature of a CPU I suggest you use one of those.

Comment: Actually, I forgot to mention my graphics card... Duh! It's an AMD Radeon R9 270X 2GiB DDR5 256-bit. This http://goo.gl/Ra9c1W one

Comment: What about the resolution?  "full hd" isn't specific enough not in 2015.  What the resolution was specifically would help.

Comment: AMD's specification page for your GPU is worthless.  So I looked at the [GTX 760](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-760/specifications) to get an estimate of what sort of resolution ithe 270X might support.  The 760 supports `4096x2160` which exceeds the minimum resolution for UHD.  The 270X also is significantly slower then the GTX 670 from what I can tell.  Verify you are not attempting to push out 4K by mistake.  This might mean you have to specifically set your TV to a lower resolution before you connect it.

Comment: By Full HD I mean 1920 x 1080.

Comment: gaming, what is the refresh rate your running to both?  if you want to cool it out some forcing the v-sync on in the catalyst software, or via the game itself can give the gpu a break depending. Having it off it will push through as many frames as it can. Many PCs need a much higher ammount of flow of ambient air through the case, depending on the method the GPU uses for air flow (out back, or into the case). Analise how you could improve airflow, or the direction of it and all the fans flows.

Comment: You have something going on here and it's nothing to do with the TV resolution. Use GPU-Z to find out your GPU load. Use CPU-Z to check your CPU speeds and voltages. Provide the output of HWInfo sensors to give us an idea of what's going on.